# How set default list value if system variable is not present in typesafe configuration?

Tags: scala, config, typesafe

Here is [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) documentatioin.

According to it it is possible to override a properties like that:

```
akka {
    loglevel = DEBUG
    loglevel = ${?LOG_LEVEL}
}
```

So in that case `logLevel` will be a `DEBUG` or value from `LOG_LEVEL` system variable.

What about list configuration properties?

```
akka {
    someListProperty = ["oneValue"]
    someListProperty = [${?LOG_LEVEL}] 
}
```

In that case if system variable is not present `someListProperty` will be overrided with empty list.

How can I set default list value if system variable is not present?

Comment: Similar answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822992/hocon-substitution-default-value

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I had similiar issue.
You can do it way like this:

```
akka {
    defaultProperty = "oneValue"
    defaultProperty = ${?SYSTEM_VAR}
    someListProperty = [${akka.defaultProperty}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to have a "default" configuration and use a fallback to this configuration with the list of variables set.

For example, [this source](https://github.com/jdevelop/scalabot/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/irc/scalabot/Main.scala) uses the override of the config at line 58 and then line 92 modifies the config.