# HOCON Substitution default value

Tags: java, properties, typesafe-config, hocon

In HOCON and Typesafe Config, How do I set the default value in case of substitution.

Does it supports something like this ??

`${server.host: 'localhost'}` -> If server.host set(Either in the same configu files or through environement setting) it substitutes that if not set choose the default value

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648416/how-set-default-list-value-if-system-variable-is-not-present-in-typesafe-configu

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the official docs on [substitutions](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#substitutions):

> If a substitution with the ${?foo} syntax is undefined:
>
> - if it is the value of an object field then the field should not be created. If the field would have overridden a previously-set value for
>     the same field, then the previous value remains.

So here is one possible workaround using [object merging](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#duplicate-keys-and-object-merging):

```
defaults {
  foo: "default Value"
}

item = ${defaults} {
  foo: ${?bar}
}
```

Or even simplier:

```
item = {
  foo: "default Value"
  foo: ${?bar}
}
```